# CSS positioning of div elements

Tags: html, css

I have a form control that I'm trying to position on a page. I've used absolute positioning which works perfectly in IE. However the position is very off in Firefox. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

```
#Control-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#Control  {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    left:100px;
    top:790px;
}

<div id="Control-wrapper">
     <div id="Control" class="HideDiv">
        <%Html.RenderPartial("MyControl")%>                
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: could you please paste more of your code? There are a number of differences between the two browsers that could cause this. Have you tried resetting margins and padding? I'd recommend having a look with Firebug which is a great tool for diagnosing problems like this

Comment: Clarified question. Not really nesting forms :)

Comment: Could you post the html source of the page (`view source` in browser), since that's what the browser works with, *not* the server-side code that you've posted (I'm guessing ASP or .NET?)

Comment: I ended up using jQuery to position my control. I wrapped the control in a div an used $("#ControlDiv").insertBefore("#PlaceHolder"). Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 3):

You're nesting forms. That's forbidden.

> <!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ **-(FORM)** -- interactive form -->

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: The control is rendered outside of the main form. I'm trying to position the form on my page in a certain location. So they are not really nested.

Comment: Then the problem is likely that you are trying to get things of variable size of line up using pixels, which is always fraught with frustration. I think more detail would be needed to find a solution. (I suspect the best solution is *do not use ASP.NET web forms*.)